# Finding total of bracket pairs and amount of matches in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created two functions to return True/False if the brackets in a statement match or not. My question is how would I use this to not only open and read a file but also count the amount of matching pairs and state as well if all pairs match. This is my code below: (also, the imported stack is just a simple class stack I created)

```
from stack import Stack
def parChecker(symbolString):
    s = Stack()
    balanced = True
    index = 0
    while index < len(symbolString) and balanced:
        symbol = symbolString[index]
        if symbol in "([{":
            s.push(symbol)
        else:
            if s.is_empty():
                balanced = False
            else:
                top = s.pop()
            if not matches(top,symbol):
                balanced = False
        index = index + 1
    if balanced and s.is_empty():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def matches(open,close):
    opens = "([{"
    closers = ")]}"
    return opens.index(open) == closers.index(close)


parenthesis= "()()(((("
print(parChecker(parenthesis))
```

And I need it to return something like this:

```
Enter the file name: test1.py

    () pairs: 2
    {} pairs: 1
    [] pairs: 2
    All () matched.
    Not all {} matched.
    All [] matched.
```

Comment: Have you had a go at building this yourself?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr   Yes, I did the opening of the file, but I am having a hard time getting the amount of pairs and how to specify for each type if it matched or not, instead of just saying it did not match. Can I do what I want already using my two functions or what do I need to modify?

Comment: @no_sleep, If you are only looking for each of these factors independently, there is no need for a stack object. You can simply check if the number of opening parenthesis is equal to the number of closing parenthesis, and after that the number of those pairs.